# visual svn server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

we have several software projects that we want to store them on different 
repositories on different locations, but unfortunately all repositories are stored in a single folder in visual svn server. Is there any way to store do that?

Or is it possible to have more than one repository in different locations?

Comment: anything svn export can't handle?

Answer (score 1):

Visual SVN is a prepackaged combination of several things including Apache Tomcat. You can assemble these yourself without Visual SVN and then configure it any way you like.

The other option is to put additional Visual SVN servers on other machines.

However, the question is what you are trying to achieve. For example you can have plenty of repositories on one server and plenty of projects in each repository. So long as you place the folder with the data on a large enough drive you will see that (virtually) you won't run out of space. Monitor the size and you should notice that it doesn't really require a lot of space.

What are you trying to achieve that is not covered by this?

Comment: Hello 
Thanks by your answer , but we want to have discrete  repositories on each drive for separate projects.
One of problems that it make me challenged , is that : How projects store into the repository (and you have pointed to it.) for example in each revision whole project store in the specified folder or the difference between 2 latest version ?
And would you please tell me that how can i configure the Apache for doing that ?(having more than one repository on different location )
best regards ,
zahra babaei

Comment: If I understand it correctly you'd like to have one SVN server storing different repositories in different locations (e.g. folders and/or drives). I don't know how to do it with the stand-alone SVN server, and don't even know whether it can be done in the first place. I've never had the need beyond the scenarios described in my answer. Our biggest repository is about 6 GBytes of data on the server. And that includes database backups with a size of about 500 MBytes. SVN is very efficient with storing just the delta even for binary files. How expensive is a TB? I probably just don't understand.